# Does one stop error warrant reimaging a machine?

Tags: windows-7, bsod, symantec

I was setting up a Thinkpad W530 from a Windows 7 image and unexpectedly got the blue screen of death. Two main points the message red:

`DRIVER_NOT_LESS_OR_EQAUL` and `Teefer3.sys`. Does anyone have any guidance as to when I should reimage the system and start from scratch? My boss is very conservative and would want me to start from scratch but I'm trying to save time to work on other deadlines.

I red the Teefer3.sys is used by Symantec programs, which are installed on the machine.

Comment: have you used this image before?

Comment: @Keltari yes many times

Comment: update Symantec to the latest version.